# Networking : Setting up multiple gateway network

Tags: networking, router, routing, gateway

[image: screenshot description]

**What I want to do?**

I want to connect my main PC to 3 different ISPs one for each of my network adapters. (2 LAN cards + 1 wireless)

**What I did ?**

I Connected two of my routers together using ethernet cable and put them on same Network (the Red network on my diagram image)

Basicly
I made the Router 192.168.0.1 to be the main one. and made the 192.168.0.2 to be the secondary one. then connected a cable from router 192.168.0.1 to another router 192.168.0.5 so it can broadcast the wireless signal and hooked an ethernet cable to my pc to it.
On my PC- I made a static IP address for my Ethernet connection as following
PC IP - 192.168.0.111 / 255.255.255.0 using Gateway and DNS 192.168.0.1 With metric 1
Then I made a static IP4 for my wireless connection as following
192.168.0.150 / 255.255.255.0 using Gateway and DNS 192.168.0.1 with metric 40

When I did all that. everything was working exactly as I wanted. but then

**Issue**

I left my PC running for a day or so. when I returned my PC cannot connect to the 192.168.0.1 Router no matter what.
it says that My PC is connected to the network but no internet access.

I tried reseting the routers / restarting my pc. disconnecting the cables. every possible thing. I have no idea what have happend that it suddenly stopped working.

**The Question**

Am I doing it wrong ? as am I not supposed to have 2 Gateways on same network ?
Is there a better way to configure my network ?

Comment: What do you mean by "make the router the main/secondary one"?

Comment: Can you ping the other network 192.168.1.1? What does the computer say, if you try to ping 192.168.0.1? Can you ping the gateway from the router itself?

Comment: my 192.168.1.1 network works fine with no issues and I can ping it and all devices connected to it. - from my pc i can also ping the 192.168.0.1 devices as intended but I cannot connect to the 192.168.0.1 internet gateway from my pc.